# How can I query all of the items which are inside a folder, which is in turn inside a document library?

Tags: list, document-library, powershell, folder, query

I am trying to use Powershell to query my Sharepoint site so I can get a list of items to use as input in my migration script. I have a document library (Site Assets), which has a folder (Calendar Pages) in it with a bunch of .aspx pages. I'd like to migrate these pages to another site.

Using Powershell, I can get a reference to the Site Assets library with: `$web.Lists["Site Assets"]`. I can't seem to get a reference to any objects further than this, however. I've tried `$web.Lists["Site Assets"].Lists["Calendar Pages"]` and `$web.Lists["Site Assets"].Folders["Calendar Pages"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No overload of the `SPList.Folders` collection takes a string.

Try `$web.Lists["Site Assets"].RootFolder.SubFolders["Calendar Pages"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$web.Lists["Site Assets"].Folders | where { $_.Name -eq "Calendar Pages" }
```

`$web.Lists["Site Assets"].Lists["Calendar Pages"]` does not work because "Calendar Pages" is not a List, it's a folder.

`$web.Lists["Site Assets"].Folders["Calendar Pages"]` does not work because `$web.Lists["Site Assets"].Folders` is of type [SPListItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection_members.aspx) which does not allow you to index by name (only by index and guid)